# Spring Rest Post Request Enumeration property

Tags: json, spring, enums, jackson, spring-rest

I am using Spring version 4.2 with Spring boot. I have a post request 
http://localhost:3000/api/standards/
for which I have the following json request body

```
{
"standardName": "MyStandard",
"language": "Java",
}
```

All I want is to save a Standard entity. The 'language' property of the StandardEntity is of type Enum. 
My Controller method looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Standard> createStandard(@Validated @RequestBody Standard standard ) {
        standardService.createStandard(standard);
        return new ResponseEntity<Standard>(standard, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

But inside the controller the  standard.getLangauge() is always null. 
I have tried the **@InitBinder**  and adding **@JsonCreator**  to the Language enum but none of them works for me. 
My Enum looks like this

```
public enum Language {
@JsonProperty("java")Java("java"), 
@JsonProperty("sql")Sql("sql");

private String value;

private Language(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static Language fromValue(String value) {
    for (Language language : values()) {
        if (language.value.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
            return language;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Unknown enum type " + value + ", Allowed values are " + Arrays.toString(values()));
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
}

@JsonCreator
public static Language create(String value) {
    System.out.println("in json creator "+value);
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    for (Language v : values()) {
        if (value.equals(v.getShortName())) {
            return v;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: Show your enum?

Comment: Updated the question with the enum

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be "java" instead of "Java"

```
{
    "standardName": "MyStandard",
    "language": "java"
}
```

When you are sending "Java" it in not able to map it to any Enum, so ideally it should throw an exception of type HttpMessageNotReadableException, check the stack trace there should be such exception.